# Perl Regex substituting all instances of a character with different values in different iterations

Tags: regex, perl

I have a simple question related to Regex in Perl.
Let's say I have a string `abcb` and I am iterating through a loop. All I want is both of the `b` characters in `abcb` to be substituted by the value of iterator in each loop. When I use the `$string=~s/b/$iterator/g`, it replaces all `b` by the first value of iterator.

Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict;
use warnings;

my $string="abcb";
for (my $iterator=0;$iterator<3;$iterator++)
{
    $string=~s/b/$iterator/g;
    print $string;
    print " ";          
}
```

Output Obtained: `a0c0 a0c0 a0c0`

Desired Output: `a0c0 a1c1 a2c2`

Comment: Are these hex numbers?

Comment: `print $string =~ s/b/$_/gr, " " for 0 .. 2` output `a0c0 a1c1 a2c2 `

Comment: `say join ' ', map { $string =~ s/b/$_/gr } 0..2;` (No trailing space. Adds missing newline.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code does not work because you are replacing the two `b`s inside `$string` in the first iteration of the loop. Afterwards the regex does not match any more, because there are no `b`s left. There are already two zeroes `0` in the string.

You have several options to solve this.

If you have Perl >= 5.14, you can use [the `/r` modifier](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5140delta.html#Non-destructive-substitution) on the substitution. It will return the replacement instead of doing in-place substitution.

```
my $string="abcb";
foreach my $i (0 .. 2) {
    #                        V here
    print $string =~ s/b/$i/gr;
    print " ";          
}
```

Another way is to copy `$string` to a new variable inside of the loop. Make sure it's a lexical (with `my`), because it's good style in Perl do declare variables in the smallest scope needed.

```
foreach my $i (0 .. 2) {
    my $copy = $string;
    $copy =~ s/b/$i/g;
    print $copy, " ";          
}
```

In all cases, I have replaced your C-style `for` with a more perlish `foreach` (though the `for` and `foreach` keywords are completely interchangeable in Perl). That does the same thing, but is way easier to read.

Comment: @ikegami right. I should have tried that, but I didn't have a perl when I was writing it.